# No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/api/encodedurl] in DispatcherServlet with name ''

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

I am writing a JUnit test case for an API but getting error as `No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/api/encodedurl] in DispatcherServlet with name ''`
I wasted more than 2 days not getting any solution checked every possible thing for this. API is token free already.

Here is my code

**Encoder Rest Test**

```
package com.zoylo.admin.web.rest;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;    
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mockito;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.AutoConfigureMockMvc;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockBean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.mock.web.MockHttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MockMvc;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.MvcResult;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.RequestBuilder;
import org.springframework.test.web.servlet.request.MockMvcRequestBuilders; 

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = EncoderRest.class)
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class EncoderRestTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private EncoderBll encoderBll;

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Test
    public void save() throws Exception {
        // mock output
        EncoderMV mv = new EncoderMV();
        mv.setPaymentUrl("www.paytm.com");
        Mockito.when(encoderBll.createPaymentUrl(Mockito.any(EncoderVM.class))).thenReturn(mv);

        EncoderVM vm = new EncoderVM();
        vm.setBookingId("ICICI090");
        vm.setType("Payment");

        String requestBody = mapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(vm);
        RequestBuilder requestBuilder = MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/encodedurl")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(requestBody).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(requestBuilder).andReturn();
        MockHttpServletResponse response = result.getResponse();
        assertEquals(HttpStatus.CREATED.value(), response.getStatus());

    }

}
```

**EncoderRest**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class EncoderRest {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Autowired
    private EncoderBll encoderBll;


    @PostMapping("/encodedurl")
    public ResponseEntity<?> generateEncodedUrl(@RequestBody EncoderVM encoderVM) {
        ......
    }
}
```

**EncoderBllImpl**

```
public class EncoderBllImpl implements EncoderBll{

    @Override
    public EncoderMV createPaymentUrl(EncoderVM encoderVM) {
        EncoderMV encoderMV = null;
        .
        .
        .   
        return encoderMV;
    }   
}
```

**Error**

> ```
> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/api/encodedurl] in DispatcherServlet with name ''
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your rest controller present in the application context that starts during the test?

Try `@SpringBootTest(classes = TestConfig.class)` instead of `@SpringBootTest(classes = EncoderRest.class)`.

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class TestConfig {

}
```

Comment: Still not working, Do i need to define anything in TestConfig?

Comment: No. So, this message `No mapping found for HTTP request` shows us that this controller doesn't present in ApplicationContext. Is your application is Spring Boot?

Comment: I created a simple Spring Boot project via Initializer and implemented some logic as You have. The test is working perfectly. So I think the problem is in application configuration and code in question doesn't have any problem.

Answer (score 0):

*No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [lanka-qr/tran/validate] in DispatcherServlet with name ''*

Not related to application context but same error occurs due to missing leading forward slash when mock perform().

My Controller have @RequestMapping and @PostMapping like this.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "aaa")

@PostMapping(value = "bbb/ccc")
```

When I perform mock like this, error occures.

```
mockMvc.perform(post("aaa/bbb/ccc")
```

Corrected as,

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/aaa/bbb/ccc")
```